# Can a Tenacious Z be Played After Drawing Two Cards?

Tags: smash-up

In the scenario where a player has 9 cards at the end of their turn and drawing two more cards gives them a **Tenacious Z**, can they discard it and play it if one hasn't already been played?

In step #5 of the rules, "Shut It Down", it states that:

> Anything that happens at the end of the turn happens here. Play passes to the player on the left.

Since **Tenacious Z** is a special card, it also states:

> Special: During your turn you many play this card from you discard pile as an extra minion. You may only use the ability of one Tenacious Z each turn.

Since a turn involves five steps, is this card still playable after drawing two more cards?

Comment: The answer is no, but I don't have time for a full answer right now. I'll come back to it later :)

Comment: I like @ryanyuyu's explanation below. I anxiously await your full answer since my initial thought process was also "no". :)

Comment: @ChrisMissal I regret that I am wrong.  I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

From the [Pretty Pretty Smash Up rules](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2014/11/SU7_Rulebook.pdf), page 10:

> **On your turn:** This means during the normal Play Cards phase of your turn.

The turn order is:

1. Start Turn
2. Play Cards *(normal time for plays)*
3. Score Bases
4. Draw 2 Cards *(and then discard)*
5. End Turn

By the time you're drawing and discarding, you've missed the window of opportunity for Tenacious Z's special. If it wanted to override this limitation, it would have to be explicit (e.g. "during any phase on your turn").

Comment: As a note, try to find the most recent expansion's rule whenever possible. They clarify confusing things from earlier games and always cover the whole set of rules.

Comment: Good catch.  I'll delete my erroneous answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah, yours was a reasonable enough interpretation that they realised that had to clarify in the later rules :)